# How to Stop proc.time being run when exiting R using quit()

Tags: r

I am running a Batch file on Windows that runs an Rscript that creates two XML files.
However at the end of the second XML file the following gets appended onto it:

```
> proc.time()

user  system elapsed 

4.97    0.62    7.78
```

Is there a way of stopping this from happening?

Regards,

Anthony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly -- if you remove the call to `proc.time()` in your script.

*Edit:* So so NOT use `R CMD BATCH foo.R` but rather `Rscript foo.R`.

Comment: proc.time() is not in the Rscript. If I run the Script directly in R, there is no problem. It creates the two files perfectly and quits at the end. The problem only arises when I run the script from a Windows Batch file. The Batch file is only one line:  c:\R\bin\Rcmd.exe BATCH "c:\Users\user\Documents\Test.R"

Comment: Thanks Very much Dirk. Once again you have solved my problem. Greatly appreciated. The batch file now reads as follows: c:\R\bin\Rscript.exe "c:\Users\user\Documents\Test.R"

Answer (score 3):

Add `q(runLast=FALSE)` to your script, or use `--no-timing`

From [the BATCH help file](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html)